# Register new user in Strapi from UI using quickstart app?

Tags: strapi

Novice strapi tester here - from the --quickstart application, after adding an admin user, the /admin/auth/register redirects to /admin/auth/login always (incognito, new browser), is this expected behavior? Is it not possible to register normal, non-admin users via the UI, or am I missing something here? I have not touched any of the permissions or other settings, but did check that sign ups are turned on (looks like by default). Is the user registration url different from /admin/auth/register?

Strapi 3.0 beta 18.4

Comment: Ok, I am guessing from this post on the Strapi blog that this is expected behavior and users cannot register via the UI - 

"An End User can only consume the API. This may include adding content but through the GET/POST methods in a form - not the Strapi dashboard." ~ https://strapi.io/blog/why-we-split-the-management-of-the-admin-users-and-end-users

If this is indeed the case then the toggle "Enable sign-ups" is misleading. Why create a separate sign up workflow when one already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the statement of User and Administrators in Strapi.

When you create your application you have no admin and no users in your application.

When you visit the admin panel for the first time, you have the same experience as Wordpress (for example) - you will need to create your first administrator.

After that, you will never see again a "register" form. Only the "login" to connect to the Admin.

To add a new admin, you will have to manually create it via the admin panel (username dropdown in the top right corner -> Manage the administrators)

About Users, Strapi doesn't provide forms but only API routes that your front end application can use to register, login, reset password, ...

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/users-permissions.html#authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking a "common" user to access the admin panel, as far as I know, it's not possible. Only admin users can access the admin panel.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, so is there a way that to register register users via the UI? How would a user sign up, or again am I missing something?